# How to force Entity Framework 4.0 to generate parameters of equivalent size to their corresponding database columns

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a very simple table called `Member`, which consists of the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member](
    [Member_MemberId] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [Member_ExternalId] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [Member_ConsumerId] [varchar](32) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Member] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Member_MemberId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I’m running a query using EF 4.0 from a datacontext as follows:

```
return Members.SingleOrDefault(member => member.ExternalId == externalId);
```

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Member_MemberId] AS [Member_MemberId], 
[Extent1].[Member_ExternalId] AS [Member_ExternalId], 
[Extent1].[Member_ConsumerId] AS [Member_ConsumerId]
FROM [dbo].[Member] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Member_ExternalId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='Paul'
```

From a performance POV, this query is suboptimal, given that it automatically casts the Member_ExternalId column as `varchar(8000)`, when the column itself is limited to `varchar(32)`.
Is there a way to force EF to generate on-the-fly parameters of size equivalent to their corresponding rows?

Comment: Why is it suboptimal to cast the parameter as varchar(8000)?

Comment: I should clarify; our resident DBA insists that it's suboptimal in terms of memory allocation. He didn't go into any more detail. What's your opinion?

Comment: He might be right in theory, but 8k isn't that much these days, and presumably it gets unallocated again pretty quickly. Do a few hundred runs of two variants of the sql statement, one with varchar(8000) and one with varchar(32) and see if there's any performance difference.

Comment: I imagine that there's a performance-hit in terms of holding the variable in memory, so that if I declare a variable of `varchar(8000)`, then 8000 bytes at an address in memory are reserved to hold the value.  I'd like to think that memory is allocated at the point at which the variable is assigned only, so that if I pass a parameter 32 bytes in size, then the LINQ parameter only consumes 32 bytes of memory. If that's the case, then there's no problem. However, if 8000 bytes are reserved, regardless of the persisted parameter's size, then it requires optimisation.

Comment: Thanks, I've reviewed similar techniques and the general consensus is that the performance-hit is negligible - far as I'm aware, this will only have a significant effect when updating rows, potentially causing page-splitting. Not too worried about that, given that I'm just reading the data. That being said, I'd still like to know whether I can force the size of the parameters generated by LINQ.

Comment: Yes, your original question is an interesting one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way of implementing this directly. I assume that it's a built-in feature to guarantee consistency across execution plans. I've replaced the query with a stored procedure in the meantime.

Comment: I would think that EF team should implement correct parameter size and type based on the model. Is it hard to implement? Should such a request be send to EF team? What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure Naomi. It's not quite a deal-breaker in terms of justifying the use of EF vs direct SQL, however it's the type of thing that DB admins generally pick up on as an issue to be optimised.

Comment: I added a suggestion to EF team about it. See https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6286842-for-char-nchar-and-varchar-nvarchar-columns-use-th and vote if you like it

Answer (score -1):

We suffered from that convertion a lot. After a bit investigation, we mapped some properties in mapping classes to tell EF to that column is not big as you think.

A SQL parameter with 8000 char length decreases query performance A LOT.
We didn't map all properties' lengths in mapping classes but we mapped when we need performance.

You can define your parameter in an EntityTypeConfiguration mapping class like this (tested):

```
Property(t => t.ExternalId)
    .HasColumnName("Member_ExternalId")
    .HasColumnType("varchar")
    .HasMaxLength(32);
```

Or you can use data annotation (not tested)

```
[Column(TypeName="varchar")]
[MaxLength(32)]
public string ExternalId {get; set;}
```

Comment: Well, doesn't the question say that this doesn't affect the size of SQL parameters at all?